# 'QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'exec'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am new to PyQt5 and I am creating a user/pass window leading to a main window. I encountered this error after calling a class using a function to execute the main window:

```
class RPDlogin (QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RPDlogin, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('RPDlogin.ui', self)

        self.buttonlogin.clicked.connect (self.RPDlogincheck)


def RPDlogincheck(self):
            if self.login_user.text() == 'nemesis' and self.login_pass.text() == 'redherbs':
                self.loginClicked()
            else:
                QMessageBox.about(self,'Error','Invalid username or password')

def loginClicked(self):
        RPD = RPDMainWindow()
        RPD.exec()

class RPDMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RPDMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('RPDMainWindow.ui', self)
```

An error occurs saying:

```
AttributeError: 'RPDMainWindow' object has no attribute 'exec'
```

Comment: What is `playerIG`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], there's too many unknown variables here

Comment: Please give a class definition of PlayerIG.

Comment: A full stack trace would also be helpful.

Comment: Sorry bout that, I added the class so you can see

Comment: Do you ever set ``PlayerIG.armor`` after initialising ``PlayerIG``?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by setting, but I do have another block of code with same format but different function that works. Which means I have no problems inside the elements of the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided enough for me to work with, I will assume that your problem is that `PlayerIG.armor`'s type is `int`.

You can't iterate over an int.

This may be unwanted, so I reccomend you do some debugging, like `print(PlayerIG.armor)` right before that loop to figure out what it is set to. Then try and figure out where you went wrong.

Are you sure you didn't mean `PlayerIG.armors`?

*Just a side note, `dict`s are unordered, meaning that your weapons, (and armor when you get that working) will all print in the order they are stored in the memory.*

Comment: Added the Player class, sorry bout that